# Angular router root named outlet cannot be targeted from nested route

Tags: angular

Here is my [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/vk4qj0h4IuO5xBW7GMgi?p=preview). I'm trying to target a root named outlet from a nested route. It doesn't seem possible right now. For example here is my template:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="outer-outlet"></router-outlet>
```

and here is my route config:

```
{
  path: '',
  component: MainComponent,
  children: [{
    path: 'inner-outlet',
    children: [{
      path: '',
      outlet: 'inner-outlet',
      component: ModalComponent
  }, {
    path: 'outer-outlet',
    children: [{
      path: '',
      outlet: 'outer-outlet',
      component: ModalComponent
    }]
  }]
}
```

If I navigate to `/inner-outlet` the `ModalComponent` will show up. But if I navigate to `/outer-outlet` the `ModalComponent` will NOT show up.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work as both of your routes are using the primary (unnamed) outlet, so it will search inside this outlet for the outer-outlet.

You would need to create a second parent route that uses the outer-outlet.

Comment: So then my question is, where in the documentation does it say once you are in an outlet you can't target outlets outside of the one you are in? Is that what you are saying is happening?